# DataGridView Comparing Results

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using a DataGridView in order to put there some score results. But I should compare results with the last week ones and make it green or red.... if possible add the difference in front of a value.

Eg. 1400 +10

in the sample the user has 1400 points, he has 10 more points than last week.

Has anyone tried this before?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have. But what's your **question** ?

Comment: Don't put data in a GrdView. Store it as a list of classes, then use a GridView to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your DataGridView's [`CellFormatting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event to set the `BackColor` and the custom text you want displayed.

You'll do your formatting when the event fires for a cell in the column that displays this week's score.  Attempt to convert this value and the value from last week's score (in another column on the same row) to `int`s and then compare.  If the difference is not zero, use the event's `CellStyle` and `Value` properties to customize the cell's appearance.

Like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) {
        string lastScoreString = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value as string;
        int lastScore;
        if (int.TryParse(lastScoreString, out lastScore)) {
            string thisScoreString = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value as string;
            int thisScore;
            if (int.TryParse(thisScoreString, out thisScore)) {
                var scoreDifference = thisScore - lastScore;
                var formattedScoreText = string.Format("{0}   {1}", thisScore, scoreDifference.ToString("+#;-#;0"));
                if (scoreDifference > 0) {
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;  // <-- Me expressing my artistic self.
                    e.Value = formattedScoreText;
                } else if (scoreDifference < 0) {
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    e.Value = formattedScoreText;
                }
            }
        } else {
            //TODO Can't parse this week score.
        }
    } else {
        //TODO Can't parse last week score.
    }
}
```

[Code assumes last week's score is displayed in the first column (index position 0) and this week's score is in the second column]